# How to run code stored in environment variable explicitly

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to store password which is being used by other script as a environment variable. These are stored in a separate file which is being sourced anytime when a new terminal window is being opened.

The thing is, that it is insecure, so I decided it to store in a Apple Keychain and prompt user to enter password.

THE MAIN PROBLEM: I don't want it to run when sourcing variables (on new term window), but explicitly - anytime I call `echo '$NAME'`, then I want to run the function stored in that variable, not on new term window.

.bash_variables:

```sh
get_pw() 
{
  key=$1
  security unlock-keychain
  security find-generic-password -a ${USER} -s $key -w
}

export E_PASSWORD="$(get_pw E_PASSWORD)"
```

This file is being sourced in `.bash_profile`:

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_variables ]; then
    . ~/.bash_variables
fi
```

Comment: Not possible. You can't have code execute when a variable is evaluated; there is no such feature. Variables have static, fixed values.

Comment: Short answer: it's not possible. I think the only possible way is to patch bash.

Comment: If you need a password to authenticate scripted/programmed operations, then you have the wrong authentication scheme. A password is meant for human to machine authentication. When authenticating between machines/scripts/programs, you want to use a token or similar authentication scheme that is designed for this purpose. Storing a clear password in a file, in a variable is creating a vulnerability.

Comment: what's wrong with $(get_pw E_PASSWORD) in any place you would use $E_PASSWORD ?

Comment: @LéaGris The other script of mine , which I trigger manually, uses this variable. I don't want to store it plain, but I still want full control over it - not being accessible when I accidentaly leave my computer unlocked or other stuff.

Comment: @Sorin I made the get_pw function generic to be used with any key to be got from Apple Keychain

Comment: @MCFreddie777 still I don't understand, it's simply a matter of having writing "$(get_pw kkkxdfalkfdj)" instead of "${kkkxdfalkfdj}"

Comment: Make sure the environment of your command is not visible to others before storing passwords in the environment.

Comment: @Sorin E_PASSWORD sent to the get_pw is only the key for the value, the real password stored in  Keychain.

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't recommend this approach in any environment that needs to be secure, but you can use the DEBUG trap.

```
function set_pw() {
    if echo $BASH_COMMAND | grep '${*E_PASSWORD}*'; then 
        E_PASSWORD="$(get_pw E_PASSWORD)"
    else
        E_PASSWORD=""  
    fi
}
trap set_pw DEBUG
```

Explanation:

- the DEBUG trap is executed before any command is executed
- `$BASH_COMMAND` is the command that is about to be executed
- `${*E_PASSWORD}*` checks if the `$BASH_COMMAND` tries to access the `$E_PASSWORD` variable (note that it doesn't take in account non interpolated strings (`'$E_PASSWORD'`)
- the else branch "deletes" the value when is not used (security ??)

**NOTE:** this is just an example! I'm not a security expert, so I can't even begin to understand the implications!